# Как сделать, чтобы MessageBox не сопровождалась звуком?

Tags: c, winapi

Код на Си для WinAPI, приведённый ниже, издаёт звук. Как сделать, чтобы он работал тихо?

```
MessageBox ( NULL, "text", "text", MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_TOPMOST | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONINFORMATION );
```

Comment: в данном случае - никак

Comment: можно перед показом сообщения побежать и выключить звук сообщений (или громкость выкрутить), а потом снова вернуть  назад.

Comment: Уберите `MB_ICONINFORMATION`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: @0Zerro: Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это встроенная фича системного `MessageBox`'а: если отображается иконка с информацией, проигрывается звук. Перенастроить это, судя по всему, нельзя, но можно просто убрать флаг `MB_ICONINFORMATION`.

Альтернативное решение — переписать самому `MessageBox` с нуля — слишком сложное. Но, конечно, тоже будет работать.